# Serviço de aplicativo com o mesmo nome no Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure

Se eu excluir um serviço de aplicativo no Azure, posso criar outro serviço de aplicativo com o mesmo nome?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você pode.

Talvez o *Azure* possa demorar um pouco para identificar que o aplicativo não exista mais e ainda assim mostrar um erro dizendo que o nome já está sendo usado.

Atualize a página e espere um pouco que o nome estará disponível novamente.

Se tiver muito azar, nesse meio tempo alguém possa criar um recurso/aplicação de mesmo nome, mas é muito difícil acontecer.

Comment: Meu problema agora é o seguinte: 
Tenho serviço de aplicativo(ApiRest) no Azure que começou apresentar lentidão absurda. A princípio pensei que fosse o plano de serviço de aplicativo em que estava hospedado, mas não é.  Quando pego essa mesmo serviço e publico no Azure com outro nome funciona perfeitamente, mas com o nome 'original' não está funcionando. Alguém tem alguma sugestão para me dar nesse sentido?

Obs: O serviço fica em estado Running, porém fica muito lento.

Comment: Qual região está o aplicativo? Um provavelmente está na América do Norte ou até mais longe e o outro no Sul do Brasil (o que está mais rápido).